# angular service-worker - handling push notification click

Tags: angular, angular5, web-push, angular-service-worker

How do I handle the push notification click in angular service worker. The SWPush does not have any methods.

I have tried referencing a js which listens to the "notificationclick" event handler but it never got fired on the click of the notification button.

Answer (score 4):

Call [SWPush#requestSubscription](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwPush#requestSubscription).
Here's a [good article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-2-practice-3221471269a1)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to update angular to at least Angular version 7.1.0 ( I would suggest to maintain up to date ). With this, you can now subscribe to `notificationClicks`

In the constructor inject `SwPush` then use it with:

```
   this.swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe( arg =>
   {
     console.log(
       'Action: ' + arg.action,
       'Notification data: ' + arg.notification.data,
       'Notification data.url: ' + arg.notification.data.url,
       'Notification data.body: ' + arg.notification.body,
     );

  });
```

If you don't want to update you should watch the file `ngsw-worker.js` with `Webpack` or `gulp` or etc. And then after the line with
`this.scope.addEventListener('push', (event) => this.onPush(event));`
add the following:

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    console.log('Notification event', event);
    event.notification.close();
    var payload = event.notification.data;

    if (event.action && payload.actions && payload.actions.includes(event.action) 
       clients.openWindow && event.notification.data.url) {
      event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to update my package.json to:

"@angular/service-worker": "7.1.0"

then this worked for me:

```
this.swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('clicked', result);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('clicked', result);
    });
```

This is working. But it doesn't show usefull data to route