# click of angular fcm notification Angular6

Tags: angular6

I'm getting the **fire base cloud messaging(fcm)** notification  and token from backend using nodejs but stuck with clicking on the notification and redirecting in to the website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular service-worker - handling push notification click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310191/angular-service-worker-handling-push-notification-click)

Comment: I think you should add more info. I flag the question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310191/angular-service-worker-handling-push-notification-click/55221858#55221858 where I think is the solution to your problem. There are two versions, for angular > 7 and for angular <7